# System variable or git call: How to find the path of the GIT repo?

Tags: git, makefile, path, continuous-integration

In our git repository we have a bunch of Makefiles and other scripts.
We try to work using absolute path whenever possible. To keep it potable, they all reference to the top folder of our git repository.

Example:

> /home/botnic/myrepo/path/to/great/script

would be stored as

> $(REPO_PATH)/path/to/great/script

Now there are several ways to find the path to the repository:

a) Use a environment variable

```
  $ export git_root=/home/botnic/myrepo
```

In every makefile/script:

```
mySuperTarget: 
  @echo $(git_root)
```

- no need to define anything
- may be confusing if set wrong. For example if the user has two copies of the repo.

b) Use a git command

```
git_root = $(shell git rev-parse --show-toplevel)

mySuperTarget:
  @echo $(git_root)
```

- Could be slower
- Should always be right

c) Some different way we did not think of...

**What other points should be considered when deciding for the one or  the other variant?
What does work better or is more commonly used in CI environments?
What do you use and why?**

Comment: You should use *git rev-parse*.  Accurate is more important.  However you should use `:=` in the assignment so it's only done one time.  You can even use `export git_root := $(shell ...)` then only do this if it's not already set, so you can do it only once per invocation of `make` (assuming all sub-makes etc. will always be in the same Git repo and you're not using git modules or something like that where you want to find the current repo).

Comment: @MadScientist IMHO the primary "you should"-recommendation would be to switch back to relative paths. I fail to see the difference in effort and stability of relative paths vs. getting all paths right with the `$(git_root)` prefix except that you are now depending on another tool peculiarity.

Comment: @Vroomfondel The advantage is, that I don't need to care about from where the script is executed. The path stay the same.